# Julia optimization reaching maximum number of iterations

Tags: optimization, julia, minimization

I have a (relatively) simple function which I want to minimize over 10 parameters in Julia. Defining the parameters list `params` and the function `example_func`, I then utilize the Optim.jl package:

```
r = optimize(x->example_func(x, J, K, G), params, NelderMead())
```

For certain values of the parameters, it converges nicely. However, for certain values of the parameters, I get the following error message:

```
* Status: failure (reached maximum number of iterations)

* Candidate solution
  Final objective value:     -1.148303e+00

* Found with
  Algorithm:     Nelder-Mead

* Convergence measures
   √(Σ(yᵢ-ȳ)²)/n ≰ 1.0e-08

* Work counters
   Seconds run:   3  (vs limit Inf)
   Iterations:    1000
   f(x) calls:    1391
```

I cannot show the explicit form of the function.

My question is if there is a better way to minimize some generic function over several parameters to ensure convergence? Can I increase the maximum number of iterations in Optim.jl? Is there some better method than Optim.jl to perform this task in Julia?

Comment: If you cannot show the explicit form of the function, then I don't think there is an answer to whether or not there is a better way to find the minimum. Guaranteeing convergence of an optimization problem for _any arbitrary input_ is a restatement of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if there is a better way to minimize some generic function over several parameters to ensure convergence?

As per PaSTE's comment, this cannot be answered for a generic function.

> Can I increase the maximum number of iterations in Optim.jl?

Yes, see the `iterations` option in the [docs](https://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/stable/#user/config/).

> Is there some better method than Optim.jl to perform this task in Julia?

It depends on your problem. Optim.jl is not a method, it's a package which provides  a variety of algorithms to do the job. Have you tried them all? Otherwise, there are other packages out there to look out for, like for example BlackBoxOptim.jl, Convex.jl, Evolutionary.jl, GeneticAlgorithms.jl, to name a few. Impossible to guide you better without more information from you.